# Link variables between two text files

Tags: bash, shell-script

The following explanation is just a representation for what I would like to achieve.

I have two text files: 
The first text file `log1.txt` contain the following entries:

```
Black
Blue
Brown
Copper
Cyan
Gold
Gray
Green
```

The second text file `log2.txt` contain the following entries:

```
Ugly
Nice
cool
pretty
```

I would like to read both texts at the same time and generate the following output:

```
The first color Black is Ugly
The second color Blue is Nice
The third color Brown is cool
The fourth color Copper is pretty
The fifth color Cyan is Ugly
The sixth color Gold is Nice
The seventh color Gray is cool
The eighth color Green is pretty
```

How can I achieve the previous output using `bash` or `shell`? I tried to apply two loops at the same time :`for loop" and/or`while loop` but did not work! For example, I tried this awkward code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    for ii in $(cat log1.txt); do

echo "The first color "$i "is" $ii

done <log2.txt
done
```

I have no idea or clue how to change between "first color", "second color", ….etc

Comment: Post what you've tried so far, so we can see what tweak it might need ?

Comment: The name of the operation that you are performing on two tables in that script is a " join", for reference.  However, what you actually want is not.

Comment: What happened to _seventh_?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to ask why you want to do this in bash, rather than simply using a more capable scripting language?

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` and with `libnumbertext-tools`'s `spellout` on Debian:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
colors=(${(f)"$(<log1.txt)"})
adjectives=(${(f)"$(head -n ${#colors} <log2.txt)"})

/usr/lib/libnumbertext/spellout -l /usr/share/libnumbertext/en \
  -p ordinal 1-$#colors |
for color adjective in ${colors:^^adjectives}; do
  read num &&
  print -r The $num color $color is $adjective
done
```

(note that it's US-English. For instance, for 101, you get *one hundred first* instead of *one hundred and first*)

If you can't install `zsh` or any software that spells out numbers but have a list of English ordinals in a third `log3.txt` file, you could do in most shells including `bash` (Bourne-like, rc-like, fish at least):

```
#! /bin/sh -
awk '
  BEGIN {while ((getline a < "log2.txt") > 0) adjective[na++] = a}
  {
    if ((getline num < "log3.txt") <= 0) num = NR "th"
    print "The "num" color "$0" is "adjective[(NR-1)%na]
  }' log1.txt
```

(falling back to `<digits>th` if we run out of English numbers).

Comment: unfortunately I don't have zsh on Centos 7 to test it. thank you

Comment: @Kasper, try `sudo yum install zsh`, or install in your home directory from source. You'd need that `spellout` utility as well.

Comment: No creative use of `paste` and a multiply-repeated `log2.txt`?  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP, the _multiply-repeated_ would get ugly  anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell does not know English, so automatically generating the spelled-out numbers with correct suffixes to an arbitrary count would involve some additional effort. With just digits for the numbering and the additional presumption that log1.txt is the longer file, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
log1_length=$(wc -l <log1.txt)
log2_length=$(wc -l <log2.txt)

for i in $(seq $log1_length); do
    arg1=$(head -$i <log1.txt | tail -1)
    arg2=$(head -$(((i-1) % log2_length + 1)) <log2.txt | tail -1)
    echo "Color No. $i $arg1 is $arg2."
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using **case control structure** as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
log1_length=$(wc -l <log1.txt)
log2_length=$(wc -l <log2.txt)

for i in $(seq $log1_length); do 
    arg1="$(head -$i <log1.txt | tail -1)"
    arg2="$(head -$(((i-1) % log2_length + 1)) <log2.txt | tail -1)"
   # Case control structure to replace digit equivalent in words 
    case ${i} in
        1) echo -n "The first color ";;
        2) echo -n "The second color ";;
        3) echo -n "The third color ";;
        4) echo -n "The fourth color ";;
        5) echo -n "The fifth color ";;
        6) echo -n "The sixth color ";;
        7) echo -n "The seventh color ";;
        8) echo -n "The eighth color ";;
        9) echo -n "The ninth color ";;
       10) echo -n "The tenth color ";;
       11) echo -n "The eleventh color ";;
    esac 
    echo ${i}"$i${arg1} is ${arg2}" |  tr -d '0123456789'   
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
The first color Black is Ugly
The second color Blue is Nice
The third color Brown is cool
The fourth color Copper is pretty
The fifth color Cyan is Ugly
The sixth color Gold is Nice
The seventh color Gray is cool
The eighth color Green is pretty
```

Comment: Why echo the digits and then delete them again?

Comment: Why the `digit=$(echo $i)`? and `echo $digit  | tr -d '0123456789'`?

Comment: @Sam, if you  `echo $digit` the output is something like `The first color 1
`. Given that the OP would like to see `The first color black is ugly` and to get around that just trim the numbers out

Comment: Note that it runs 8 commands for each line of log1. Using those head+tail for each line means the  files have to be read from the start at each iteration which is going to be even less efficient than [using while read loops](/q/169716)

Comment: So  why outputting that digit in the first place (twice with $digit$i) just to remove it later with tr (which would also remove digits in color names or adjectives). Also why `digit=$(echo $i)` and not `digit=$i` (or `for digit` instead of `for i`).

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised nobody has suggested using arrays.  Here is my crude attempt (using the `log3.txt` idea from @Stephane above.

```
#!/bin/bash

nl1=$( wc -l < log1.txt )
nl2=$( wc -l < log2.txt )
nlnums=$( wc -l < nums.txt )

declare -a arr1[$nl1]
declare -a arr2[$nl2]
declare -a nums[$nlnums]

for (( i=0; i < $nl1; i++ ))
do
    read arr1[$i]
done < log1.txt

for (( i=0; i < $nl2; i++ ))
do
    read arr2[$i]
done < log2.txt

for (( i=0; i < $nlnums; i++ ))
do
    read nums[$i]
done < nums.txt

j=0
for (( i=0; i < $nl1; i++ ))
do
    echo "The ${nums[$i]} color ${arr1[$i]} is ${arr2[$j]}"
    j=$(( (j+1) % $nl2 ))
done
```

The file `nums.txt` is as follows:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
ninth
tenth
```

The code needs to be cleaned a bit but illustrates the point.

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, can you please explain why you downvoted?